# Not getting the expected result in filter transformation for RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, rdd

I have loaded a text file and applied transformation (filter)  but not getting expected result .code  and result is below

```
stopwords = ['MP','UP']
2
rdd3 = ARDD.filter(lambda x: x not in stopwords)
3
rdd3.take(10)
(2) Spark Jobs
Out[22]: ['MP , rajasthan, UP , Kashmir , delhi , haryana , punjab ']
```

Comment: if you are working in  pyspark then why are you using RDD and not DataFrame????

Comment: @AtlasBravoos   I have used pyspark in dataframe . so i was trying with RDD . is it the cause  for this issue ?

Comment: what is ARDD? please elaborate

Comment: @PrathikKini  i just named a RDD ARDD

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be `ARDD` contains one string element with all your words.
Try to load your data differently to have one word by line and your filter will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
ARDD = sc.parallelize(['MP' , 'rajasthan', 'UP' , 'Kashmir' , 'delhi' , 'haryana' , 'punjab'])
stopwords = ['MP','UP']
rdd3 = ARDD.filter(lambda x: x not in stopwords)
rdd3.take(10)

Out[10]: ['rajasthan', 'Kashmir', 'delhi', 'haryana', 'punjab']
```